# tikzrput : undefined control sequence \rput

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am having some weird trouble with the `tikzrput` package.

I use it on my Macbook with TeX Live and it works perfectly.
On the other hand on my Ubuntu at work (with TeX Live too) it really does not want to work.

Every `\rput` line gives me after compilation something like:

```
Undefined control sequence \rput{0}(0,3.5){$\lambda$}
```

I fear it is not a problem of integrating `tikzrput.sty` because when I remove it, the error turns into only:

```
Undefined control sequence \rput
```

Without those `\rput` lines, everything works fine (TikZ is well installed along with `pgf` on my Ubuntu).

Could this be a problem of compatibility between `tikzrput` and my TikZ version? (everything is upgraded to the last version).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`).

Comment: Did you see [Problem with keys to emulate \rput with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45351/problem-with-keys-to-emulate-rput-with-tikz)? I've created a folder which contains `tikzrput.sty` from the answer and a `test-tikzrput.tex` copying again the example provided by [Alain Matthes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3144/alain-matthes). It works!

Comment: Okay, now that's really weird : I deleted and downloaded tikzrput.sty many times and it never worked.
This time I created it myself by pasting the code from Alain Matthes in my own tikzrput.sty, and everything works fine !