# TikZ library for Computer Science

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a Computer Science library for TikZ?

I am looking for a library for drawing standard data structures (array, linked list, stack, queue, pointers, trees, etc) in a consistent way.

I would also be happy to hear how hard would it be to create such a library for an intermediate LaTeX user (understands some macros, can't write macros independently) in terms of work-days.

Comment: I think that such a library does not exist but I'm not sure. Do you have a link to show us what you desire. Something like that : http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/43stack/ ?

Comment: Yes, something like that. I have created some illustrations in TikZ without the use of such a package, and I would like to either write my own package or use an existing one to achieve better consistency and make life easier. The document in question is at http://ilijapavlic.com/spa/Skripta.pdf

Comment: CTAN lists several packages that may be useful for computer scientists [here](http://www.ctan.org/characterization/secondary/subject-specific-typesetting/computer-science/), but unfortunately none provides constructions for standard data structure types.

Comment: @ipavlic: See also the question [Inconsistent TikZ multipart node anchors][1].


  [1]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44257/inconsistent-tikz-multipart-node-anchors

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, there is no a dedicated Computer Science tikz library. But it is not hard to realize why **there is no need for one**, as you can achieve almost anything you want with four basic tikz libraries:

- \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
- \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
- \usetikzlibrary{trees}
- \usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

In [this website](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/area/computer-science/) you can find a comprehensive list of examples for many Computer Science applications, including the ones you mention. The page includes the `.tex` file for each example. If you see the code of these examples, there is no use of any specialized package (with [this exception](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-inet)) but only a clever combination of the above.