# Should I make my include file into a package?

Tags: packages, include

I wrote an include file to allow me to draw certain diagrams (that have various different parameters) conveniently, by just calling macros within a tikzpicture. This file is now at about 1500 lines, although a fair amount of that is notes I wrote (in the form of TeX comments) on the various macros in case I come back later and need to remember quickly how they work. Or I suppose, in case someone else wants to use it.

Anyway, I include this file in the preamble of my document just using the `\input` control sequence. But I know that the "standard" way of making reusable code is to create something called a "package". What extra work (if any) is involved in making this include file into a package, and how will I benefit (if at all)?

Comment: Please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48881/963 it requires minimum effort.

Comment: no work at all, just rename the file from .tex to .sty

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What is the purpose of `\ProvidesPackage` etc. then?

Comment: It's a useful, but optional declaration, so when someone posts here and something doesn't work you can ask tex to reveal what version of the package you have but you don't have to use `\ProvidesPackage` with `\usepackage` any more than you have to use `\ProvidesFile` with `\input`. The two issues are totally separate.

Comment: There are some advantages, too, if you choose to use them. You can use warning/informational/checking commands available to package authors. You can easily set the package up to give you information in the output and log. You can also use @ etc. without needing to say \makeatletter...\makeatother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing that you *need* to do to change a file that you `\input` into a package is change the extension to `.sty` (actually LaTeX doesn't require even that, the association of an extension with the package system is part of the system dependent part of latex, but all currently active latex distributions do use that).

It is common to add `\ProvidesPackage` so that you can declare a file date and version, however that is an optional extra step, and  TeX files that you `\input` may use the similar `\ProvidesFile` command (although that gets used a lot less than `\ProvidesPackage` in practice).